# True or False? Basic logic problem. for all x for all y, x > y if and only if U = 0

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

"The domain $U$ is considered a sub-set  of $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this statement true? $\forall x \forall y, x > y  \leftrightarrow   U =  \emptyset$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U$ is empty, then the statement on the left is trivially true. If $U$ is not empty, then let $x \in U$ be arbitrary. Since $x \not\gt x$, the statement on the left is false. Therefore the two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

True. If U is not empty then there is some element in U such that x = y and that will fail the test. Assume there is some a,b in U such that a is greater than b. Than the statement also says that b cannot be in U since b is not greater than a. However than that is a contradiction from the above assumption.